# SQL Server DMV sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors for Grafana

Tags: sql-server, grafana, influxdb, telegraf, dmv

Currently I am using Grafana with Telegraf and InfluxDB to develop a monitoring solution for SQL Server.

I would like to know if there is a method to retrieve the results for SQL Server DMV **sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors** in Grafana.

Comment: Step back from Grafana for a second. Any query you run for monitoring intends to tell you something about the system being monitored. What information would you like to get out of this table and what question(s) would you like it to answer?

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the response. I am trying to capture the buffer pool size of each database. This I am able to do using the query mentioned in the below page. http://dbadiaries.com/sql-server-how-to-find-buffer-pool-usage-per-database

Comment: My purpose is to find something similar using Grafana as well. So that it can be visualized.

Comment: Sure. From what I've seen of the Telegraf/Influx/Grafana pipeline, you write the query, it runs the worry on a periodic basis and store the results with a timestamp at which point the data is available to graph. If that's the case, which part do you need help with?

Comment: I can query the influxdb to get the data from SQL which was polled by telegraf. But I am unable to find any data related to sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors in influxdb. So was checking for options to get the data. As an alternative, I will have to write a query to fetch data from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors dmv from sql in grafana which I am not able to figure out as there is no time column in sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors.

Comment: Got the resolution. Added the same SQL query given in dbadiaries.com using MS-SQL as the source. As there is no time column in the dmv, had to display the output in table format. Telegraf is installed on the same server where grafana and influxdb are installed. So had to add a data source for the instance which had to be monitored and ran the SQL query which gives result in tabular format.Need to figure out a method to display the result in graph format.